jest not able to understand "export default" in a specific file
I have package called sinon js installed to my react app, I have version 5.0.10 of it which is deprecated.
So I decided to upgrade it to latest version which is 18.0.0
This package is used in my test files like this by importing it and create the fake server from it and so on.
And on the old version of it all the test cases that I have was working perfectly fine.
The problem :
when upgraded the version of this package and run the tests cases again it keeps giving me an error about export default syntax in a new file add to this package.
This is the error provide by jest
So jest is no longer can understand this file because it's not written in commonJs syntax.
I have searched and tried multiple solution but none of them worked,
i just want to force jest to transform any new file in Node_modules
which is not written in CommonJs syntax.
Here are an additional info about my current setUp for jest and babel.
The file path inside node_modules which cases the error :
node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-esm.js
jest : those are the current transform and transformIgnorePatterns values.
"transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],

bablerc file : these are the current babel config that I have.
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
    },
    "icons": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
    }
  },
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "lodash",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining"]
  ]
}

And here are the rules for js and jsx files in my webpack config:
 {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread', 'lodash'],
        },
      },


As far as I can, you updated your SinonJS package (13 version) and it no longer supports the old syntax. I would:

A: Just try updating your code, it's unrealistic to think what worked in v5 applies to v18.
B: Try modifying your package.json file to allow for older Javascript syntax. Using the ES Modules

package.json
{
    "type": "commonjs"
}

It should be noted that CommonJS is considered legacy at this point but is not outright deprecated.

thank you for you contribution,
it's not about the version itself,
there is a specific version ( I think it's version 10) that has this new update which is adding a new file called sinon-es.js to the package.
it meant that if i use any version which does not contain that new ESM file everything would work fine,
and adding the "type: commonJs" to the package.json didn't solve the problem.
